# uploading IAP to Apple

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am uploading an app to Apple for review. This app will be free and have an IAP available from within.  When uploading the app to Apple for review, since the content is simply locked and therefore present, just locked, would this still be considered as Apple-hosted content or not? When uploading the binary of the free app to Apple, would I need to include a .pkg file of the app with the locked content. It seems that I would not have to include the .pkg file because it is already there, just locked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the IAP is already a part of the app then no, it's not considered hosted content.  That counts only for separate downloadable content, such as new levels, images, or other data that needs to be downloaded to the app.

Comment: thanks so much! that really helps. I searched all over and even at developer.apple forums and could not find that answer.